how to create this zoom in and zoom out interactive function in the website
Does anyone know how or what kind of word can I search for to build a website like 'Scale of universe'(https://scaleofuniverse.com/en
) with a interface that creative a space and allow viewers to zoom in and zoom out like time travel video in sci-fi movie?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
